# LaTeX suppress page break

Tags: latex

I'm trying to create a LaTex document which has a "testday" and a verse full of "testItemToDo" and I want any page break to occur before the "testday" but never between a "testday" and the verse of "testItemToDo".  How can I modify my LaTex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
{*}{*}to do\\
\begin{verse}
{*}today\nopagebreak
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
{*}testDay\nopagebreak
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
{*}testDay\nopagebreak
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
{*}testDay\nopagebreak
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
{*}testDay\nopagebreak
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on TeX.SE

Comment: Can we migrate it to TeX.SE somehow?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Surround your testday and verse with a `\begin{samepage}` and `\end{samepage}`, i.e.:

```
\begin{samepage}
{*}testDay
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\end{samepage}
```

This still allows the verse to break a page fine, provided you get rid of some `\\*`.

Comment: Enclosing a `tabbing` environment with `samepage` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Turion see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960276/1168342) with `\filbreak` - it could help.

Answer (score 35):

`\nopagebreak[number]`

The `\nopagebreak` command prevents LaTeX from breaking the current page at the position of the command. With the optional argument, number, you can convert the `\nopagebreak` command from a demand to a request. The number must be a number from 0 to 4. The higher the number, the more insistent the request is.

Or you can change your `verse` to a `minipage`... though if the list is longer than a page, latex will probably puke.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but the `samepage` solution from here [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2210749/1444073) does.

Comment: ``\nopagebreak`` epic fail

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution I've found is with `\filbreak` before each ([see the FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-nopagebrk.html)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
{*}{*}to do\\
\begin{verse}
{*}today
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\filbreak
{*}testDay
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\filbreak
{*}testDay
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\filbreak
{*}testDay
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\filbreak
{*}testDay
\begin{verse}
testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo\\*testItemToDo
\end{verse}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works a lot better for me. In my case renewing sections (`\renewcommand{\section}{\fillbreak\oldsection}`) shown in the liked FAQ is *a lot* easier, more comfortably and clearer than the `samepage` environment.

Comment: Your example seems to not use `\fillbreak`. What's up with that?

Comment: @lindhe '\filbreak' has only one l?

Comment: Oh wtf would never have noticed. And I used ctrl+f to locate it, so didn't locate it in your text either. Thanks.

Comment: However, unfortunately, `\filbreak` still does nothing for me. :/